# Horizontal page in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report

How can I design my report to use it horizontally ? I really need more fields so vertically won't show everything.

Thanks.

edited:
I need the page to be landscape instead of portrait.

Sorry, my version is 8.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to change the orientation under the printer settings for Crystal from File > Print...

As long as your printer supports landscape printing, the report will reflect the change (check printer drivers if it doesn't allow landscape but you think it should).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on if you are trying to do this at design time or run-time, and it depends on the version of Crystal Reports you are using.  Usually you go to File -> Page Setup to change the paper orientation and size.

Edit - the runtime environment for that version of Crystal doesn't support changing the paper orientation at program execution through the CrystalReport object, just when you are designing the report.  You would have to change the orientation using the printer options when selecting the printer to print to.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on your report,go to design-> page setup, there will be an orientation tab to select landscape or portrait.